# list only once filetype in combobox

Tags: vb.net, file

this code

```vb
  Try
            For Each file As String In System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(dir)
                If System.IO.Path.GetExtension(file).ToString = ".xsl" Then
                    ComboTheme.Items.Add(System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file))
                    ComboTheme.Items.Add(System.IO.Path.GetExtension(file))
                End If
            Next

        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try
```

when working, register in the text box

- blue (.xsl)
- white (.xsl)
- file (.txt)

I want only the xsl file to show in the combobox list, like this:

- blue
- white

Comment: Well, you could use `System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(dir, "*.xsl")` but it won't make much difference regarding the output. Your current code shouldn't add a file with ".txt" extension to the ComboBox. You should [step through the code](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/navigating-through-code-with-the-debugger?view=vs-2019) to understand what's going on. Also, you shouldn't swallow exceptions like this (especially while debugging). Get rid of the exception handling and step through the code; if you can't figure it out, then [edit] the question and provide more info.

Comment: Try cleaning and rebuilding your solution. You might be running an old version of code. Also remove the try catch block temporarily and update your questions with whatever exceptions are generated.

Comment: You could create a class with 3 Properties: `[P1]` for the full FileName, `[P2]` returns `GetFileNameWithoutExtension` and `[P3]` that returns `GetExtension`. Then override `ToString()` to return `"[P2] (.[P3])"`. Use a `List(Of Class)` to fill the ComboBox, setting `DisplayMember = "[P2]"`. When an item is selected, your `TextBox.Text = [SelectedItem].ToString()`

Comment: You don't need to .ToString the result of GetExtension because GetExtension returns a string already

Answer (score 0):

Not totally clear what you're asking but from the title saying "list only once" I imagine you were having a problem where unexpected things were showing in your combo box

Here's a code that works for what you say you want:

```
    Dim files as String() = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(dir, "*.xsl")
    Try
        For Each file As String In files 
            ComboTheme.Items.Add(System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file))
        Next

    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
```

It will make the combo look like

- blue
- white

If you want the combo to look like:

- blue (.xsl)
- white (.xsl)

Make the code inside the loop:

```
Dim s as String
Dim f as String = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file)
Dim e as String = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(file)
s = string.Format("{0} ({1})", f, e)
ComboTheme.Items.Add(s)
```

I would recommend you `Imports System.IO` too so you don't have to write System.Io all the time

Your code was calling Add twice which would have caused 4 item in the combo box even though there were only 2 xsl files

Comment: not that, that means that only xsl files appear
not given parentheses for file extensions

Comment: I think you're probably going to have to have a better attempt at explaining yourself then, because I'm not the only person who decided this is what you wanted